# Как определить разрешает ли удаленный сервер кросс доменные запросы?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, xmlhttprequest

Делаю кросс доменный запрос:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.example.com/v1/' + dept,
    type: 'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(response){
        alert('ajax complide');  
        alert(response);
    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('POST failed.');
    }
});
```

Но в консоли браузера вижу следующее:

**Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://192.168.135.14/Items/GetTnItemssrcList (Причина: отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).**

Как определить, это моя ошибка или это сервер не разрешает запросы?

Comment: в ответе посмотреть есть ли такой заголовок (кажется `success: function(data, textStatus, request){
        alert(request.getResponseHeader('some_header'));
   },`) и действовать

Comment: Извините а о каком заголовке идет речь?

Comment: Если сервер разрешает кросс-доменный запрос с этого домена – он должен добавить к ответу заголовок Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: Проверял вот так: console.log(responseData.getResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") );  Возвращает null... Что бы это могло значить?